# sending sms from pc to mobile

Tags: java, sms

i am using smsj api to send sms from pc to mobile through gsm modem. as given on the [page](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/), i have tried the following code.

```
package org.marre;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.marre.sms.SmsException;


public class SendMessage  {

    public void send() {
    try{

         // Send SMS with clickatell
         SmsSender smsSender = SmsSender.getGsmSender("COM7");
         String msg ="sample message";
         // International number to reciever without leading &quot;+&quot;
         String reciever = "9561356345";
         // Number of sender (not supported on all transports)
         String sender ="9561356345";
         // Connect
         smsSender.connect();
         // Send message
         smsSender.sendTextSms(msg, reciever, sender);       
         // Disconnect
         smsSender.disconnect();
    } catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("i");
    } catch(SmsException s){
        s.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("s");
    }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
        app.send();
    }


}
```

but i am getting this error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.SerialComm.<clinit>(SerialComm.java:58)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.GsmTransport.class$(GsmTransport.java:83)
    at org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.GsmTransport.<clinit>(GsmTransport.java:83)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.marre.sms.transport.SmsTransportManager.getTransport(SmsTransportManager.java:75)
    at org.marre.SmsSender.<init>(SmsSender.java:112)
    at org.marre.SmsSender.getGsmSender(SmsSender.java:180)
    at org.marre.SendMessage.send(SendMessage.java:12)
    at org.marre.SendMessage.main(SendMessage.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

i am a beginner in java. please help me with the code.

**note:**  i have used smslib api earlier for sending a simple text message. but this does not support ems messages. if you have any other library in mind which supports ems messages, please let me know. smsj was one i could easily download.

Comment: First of all, you've given us the wrong code. Where is the code for class `SiemensOtaMessage`? Also, post the full stacktrace of the code please.

Comment: @ Buhake Sindi  i have updated the question

Comment: @BuhakeSindi its 3rd part code not his code.

Comment: Download LoggerFactory jar from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html and add it in your build path

Comment: Looks like your used lib is quite old (references a very old SLF4J). Maybe try this one: http://smslib.org/

Comment: @Adrian i used smslib succesfully to send a simple text message. however it does not support sending ems messages. my main aim is to send images and short audio clips through ems message.  if u have any other java api library in mind, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real cause of the problem lies here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

The compiler couldn't find `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` from the classpath.

Download SLF4J and add the library in your classpath and compile your code.

**Note:** As smsj references a very old version of Slf4J you need to use this old version as well: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.0-beta9

Comment: i added this library to the classpath and built the project again. but still its giving the same error.

Comment: @newtoandrouid Try this one: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.0-beta9 as this is the version referenced by your lib